# How do I correct LogWatch error on Fedora 20?

Tags: linux, fedora, fedora-20

I have LogWatch running on a Fedora 20 server. Logwatch gives the following every night:

> --------------------- Connections (secure-log) Begin ------------------------
>
> **Unmatched Entries**
>
> CROND: pam_env(crond:setcred): Unable to open env file: /etc/environment: No such file or directory: 199 Time(s)
>
> crond: pam_env(crond:setcred): Unable to open env file: /etc/environment: No such file or directory: 398 Time(s)
>
> ---------------------- Connections (secure-log) End -------------------------

What could be generating these errors?

Comment: Fedora 20 is EOL. Update to some supported version to get some hints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Crond is triggering these logs. You should suppress them by creating the file

```
/etc/environment
```

Though, you should update at least to Fedora 23. If it is a bug, it will not ever get fixed in  Fedora 20, because it is years after EOL.

Comment: I don't have an F20 system to check, but from the changelog for the `setup` package, the file `/etc/environment` (which is empty by default) was added in 2004 — pre-Fedora! That file should exist.